# Convert an aif file to binary and than back in aif file iOS

Tags: ios, binaryfiles

I am new to ios.
I have in Resources a very small sound.aif file which i want to send using pjsip (pjsua_im_send) over udp.

I need to get the binary format of the .aif file in order to send it. How can i read an aif and convert a .aif in binary?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS developer examples have a handy c++ class that can help you with that:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Listings/ExtAudioFileConvert_cpp.html

Comment: aren't there any other simple examples? I just need to have a pj_str_t voiceBuffer.